# Modal presentation style from view controller embedded in a full screen navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller. I settled the navigation controller modal presentation full screen:

```swift
let firstVC = FirstViewController()
customNavigationController = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)

customNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

self.navigationController.present(customNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the "firstVC" I need to present another view controller with modal presentation style `.pageSheet`:

```swift
class FirstViewController {
   func presentSecondVC() {
       let secondVC = UIViewController()
       secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
       present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzyVj.png).

This is not what I want. I want the default presentation, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0RQu.png).

My problem is that I need the full screen presentation for all the controllers that will be presented in the flow, but only in one case I need the pageSheet presentation with the default iOS graphic.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried using modalPresentationStyle [automatic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/automatic)? You can certainly play around with other styles - and any combination. Ensure you check this on different devices and screen classes since the appearance will be different.

Comment: I want the pageSheet style for the presentation of the second view controller, so I can't use the "automatic" one and have different visualization depending on device.

I think the problem is in the presentation style of the navigation, which is full screen. @CouchDeveloper Is there a way to override the navigation presentation style only for certain views?

Comment: Your second image shows a view controller presented with "pageSheet" presenting another with "pageSheet". Your first image shows a view controller presented "fullScreen" presenting another in "pageSheet". Both are "default" representations on iOS 13 and later on an iPhone. I fear, you cannot control the appearance and animation of the _presenting_ VC. But you may research further here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate

Comment: What you probably observe is, that when you show an initial view controller (say, TabBar -> rootViewContoller) this root view controller will be shown as if it were presented fullScreen. When the root view controller presents another VC in "pageSheet", then root behaves as if it were presented with "pageSheet" (it shrinks underneath a bit). However, when you present another VC A as "fullScreen", and then A presents yet another B in "pageSheet", then A remains shown fullScreen - as opposed to the root VC.

Answer (score 0):

I think that default tools cannot help you. And way to try to manage presenting view is not good idea.

So one way to get what you want is to make custom view like standard .pageSheet view, and then you present it with .fullScreen modal presentation.